# Android bluetooth car phone interruption

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm working with a driving safety app that hooks to navigation and sends the driver voice notifications.

This works so long as the user has the car stereo selected on Bluetooth as they would for streaming music.

The issue is drivers want to be able to listen to their radio and still have the application send voice notifications add needed.

Is there a way to do this, similar to how the paired device will interrupt for a phone call and then return to the radio when the call ends?

Comment: Should you add the Android Auto tag?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks.  Created this from my phone and didn't see that tag.  It certainly can't hurt.

Comment: I was just checking if that is what you were asking for because the alternative would be some third-party bluetooth radio thingy that I doubt you'd be able to change.